# How can I properly integrate router-dom into my project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to take on this frontend mentor space tourism challenge and I have been trying to link the navbar to their respective pages before I start building but for some reasons it wont link, only the homepage contents is shown. For example, if I try to edit the address in order to go to one section of the web page it won't take me there, only the homepage contents will be displayed

This is how my app.js file look like:

```
import  React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Constants/Home/Home'
import Crew from './Constants/Crew/Crew'
import Technology from './Constants/Technology/Technology'
import Destination from './Constants/Destination/Destination'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
            <Route path="/crew" element={<Crew />} />
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/technology" element={<Technology />} />
            <Route path="/destination" element={<Destination />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>

        this is tests
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my navbar.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import logo from '../assets/shared/logo.svg'
import { Crew } from '../Constants'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className='app_navbar'>
      <div className='app_navbar_img'>
        <Link to='Crew'>
          <img src={logo} alt='logo' />
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div className='app_navbar_line'/>

      <div className='app__navbar__lists'>
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

I have been running so many trials and errors on this for days now. Now I tried to link the logo icon to the crew page, if I click on the icon I expect my screen to display the contents on my crew page but it wont. It will only display what I have in home part then I noticed it's only displaying whatever part of the page that has the `path="/"` in the routes. I have seen many videos, followed tutorials yet the problem keep persisting.

Comment: It should be `to='/crew'` instead of `to='Crew'`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Home` component is rendered twice... once as a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) (*i.e. wrapping the other nested routes*) on path `"/"`, and once again as routed component on path `"/home"`.

It doesn't seem likely that `Home` is both a layout route component and a "leaf" route component.

If `Home` is a layout route component it should render the `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render their `element` content into. It should be removed as a route on `"/home"`.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet />
    ...
  );
};
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
            <Route path="/crew" element={<Crew />} />
            <Route path="/technology" element={<Technology />} />
            <Route path="/destination" element={<Destination />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>

        this is tests
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

If `Home` ***is not*** intended to be a layout route then remove it as a wrapping parent route. If necessary, render a redirect to `"/home"` to render the home page.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
          <Route path="/crew" element={<Crew />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/technology" element={<Technology />} />
          <Route path="/destination" element={<Destination />} />
        </Routes>

        this is tests
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```